# Polars Rust convert Dataframe to Arrow-rs RecordBatch/Save Dataframe to database

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am trying to use the polars Rust to do some data analysis and want to save the data to database. It's seems that RecordBatch is required for most of the crates to save arrow format data to database.

I found there is a similar method to convert dataframe to arraw table for [python polars](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_arrow.html#polars.DataFrame.to_arrow). I would like to know is it possible to have a method to get RecordBatch from polars Dataframe for polars Rust?

Thanks.